# How to use ng-repeat filter on a non-associative array (non key-value pair array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have been trying unsuccessfully to try to find an example of how to filter on a specific column index of a simple array.  Without complicating it with my own code, I'm trying to simply modify the code found on the AngularJS site found here
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter How would I go about filtering only the name column knowing the array[0] will always be the name.

I'm trying to figure out how to write:

```
Filter only on Name <input ng-model="search.name"><br>
Filter only on Phone <input ng-model="search.phone"><br>
<table id="searchObjResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Given:

```
<div ng-init="friends = [['John', '555-1276'],
     ['Mary', '800-BIG-MARY'],
     ['Mike', '555-4321'],
     ['Adam', '555-5678'],
     ['Julie', '555-8765'],
     ['Juliette', '555-5678']]">
</div>
```

Comment: Regarding your notion about data sent over the server and repetitions, serving zipped files takes care of that, you shouldn't worry about it. Also, your array is not valid.

Comment: Perhaps you'd see it for yourself if you tried to do it first...

Comment: Well, the question comes down to rewriting an array into an object (in JS, non-associative arrays are called simply arrays, while the associative ones are called objects), so you can use the same code to iterate over an object after fetching the array from the server. Or, simply use the array format on the client and make minimal modifications to the template.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a filter function, for example:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LrKNsS6m8rbrOXIhnAfj?p=preview)

```
$scope.filterFn = function(val) {
    return !$scope.search || (val[0].toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  }
```

Or turn your array into a collection:

```
arr.map(function(p){
    return {name: p[0], phone: p[1]}
 });
```

And filtering the same way that you would in the original example.